# Get URL from background-image Property

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, trim

i am currently using this to get the url from the background-image property:

```
var url = $(this).find('div').css('background-image');
url = url.substr(4, url.length - 5);
```

This works fine however in some browser (IE6-9), instead of it being:

```
url(http://.com/)
```

its

```
url("http://.com/)
```

Is there a failsafe way that will just get the url from this property? without having to do browser detection or some other stuff?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could do:

```
url = url.replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');
```

This will remove `url('` and `url("` from the beginning of the string if it is present and `")` resp. `')` from the end.

Comment: @Ozzy: This is a good answer, but I wouldn't call it "failsafe" because if someone takes over your project and starts using multiple backgrounds...

Comment: `url.replace(/^url\(['"]?(.+)['"]?\)/,'$1');`  will be shorter

Comment: @HasanTayyarBESIK, regex is greedy, so you need to specify that you don't want quotes in your capture. ie: `url.replace(/^url\(['"]?([^'"]+)['"]?\)/,'$1');`

Comment: That is little better: `url.replace(/^url\(['"]?(.+?)['"]?\)/,'$1');` (not take the last " )