# How can i grab the source of the background on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-cycle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get URL from background-image Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397529/get-url-from-background-image-property)

I'm using the [Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) and i want to create a pager/thumbnail.

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide">
  <div class="panel" id="product">

  </div>
</div>
```

My Image is on the background of the div. Not inside the div itself

**JS Call**

`pager:'#thumbs',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>'; 
    },`

`return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>';`

I'm trying to grab the background image on `product`. So instead of returning `+ slide.src +` what would i replace this with?

The above grabs the source of the image. How can i grab the background source on the div rather than the image source?

My image is on the div not inside a `<img>` tag.

**Thanks. **

Comment: Can you be more specific on what div u want the background for

Comment: I dont think its a duplicate since it is using a jQuery Library.

Comment: Well, thedixon (and rsp and Rahul) provided exactly the same solution how to extract the URL from the CSS value, so I'd say it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure on which div you're wanting the background image of, and where you're wanting to use it, but...

`$('#product').css('background-image')` will give you the URL to the background image of the product div.

So, following on from this, in your code I *think* you'll need it changing to:

```
pager:'#thumbs', pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + $("#product").css("background-image") + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>'; },
```

**Final answer, thanks to rsp:**

```
pager:'#thumbs', pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + $("#product").css("background-image").replace('url(', '').replace(')', '') + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>'; }
```

Comment: It won't work because the `background-image` CSS property is in the form `url(http://www.example.com/image.jpg)` so you need to remove the "url(" and ")" - see my answer.

Comment: Good shout, didn't think of that!

Comment: this is almost working. However it is also grabbing the parenthesis after the URL `)`

Comment: pager:'#thumbs', pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + $("#product").css("background-image").replace('url(', '').replace(')', '') + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>'; } - that'll work, thanks to rsp.

Comment: I appreciate the help Guys. @rsp I'm going to accept this answer and up vote yours.

Comment: what if there are multiple selectors that i want to grab the background image from? for example `$("#product, #product2")` doesnt work. help please @thedixon @rsp

Comment: $("#product, #product2").each(function(i,val) { $(this).css('bacckground-image') });

Answer (score 2):

You can get the background of a div with:

```
var url = $('#yourid').css('background-image')
                      .replace('url(', '')
                      .replace(')', '');
```

You need to remove 'url(' and ')' because the CSS property looks like this:

```
url(http://www.example.com/image.jpg)
```

Answer (score 1):

without jquery, this would be

```
 document.getElementById("slide").style.backgroundImage="url('xxx.png')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = $("#product").css('background-image');

url = url.replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');

alert(url);
```

this might help