# Get divs with regex in background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, background-image

I'm trying to write a script in pure js or jQuery to catch every `<div>` with a particular regex in its CSS `background-image` property.

```
<div style="background-image: url('the_regex/http://example.org/image.jpg')>
<div style="background-image: url('the_regex/http://example.org/another.jpg')>
```

---

I'm starting with an existing, functional script that collects all `<img>` elements that have the regex in the `src=""` attribute. It's looking for elements like this:

```
<img src="the_regex/http://example.org/img.jpg">
<img src="the_regex/http://example.org/img2.jpg">
```

with this

```
  this.$imgs = $("img[src*='" + this.the_regex + "']");
```

So this works for `<img>` elements, but my site is all `<div>`s with `background-image`.

---

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397529/get-url-from-background-image-property) I know how to get the url from a given div, but I want to collect all the divs with this regex in the background-image into a single variable, so i can `each` them and remove that regex…

Fwiw, the script is [sencha-src-fallback.js](https://github.com/ultrapasty/sencha-src-image-fallback). It eventually removes the regex from the src if a certain condition is satisfied.

Comment: I don't know html, but what is background-image property, is that an attribute of the div tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine regex and the `.filter()` function to achieve what you want. Basically we run the `background-image` property retrieved using the `.css()` method, and check if they match the pattern. If they do, we return the list of elements (which you can manipulate later):

In the example below, I want the background-image to match the pattern `/http:\/\/placehold\.it/gi` (i.e. matching `http://placehold.it` and as a global and case-insensitive match), and if they do, I slide them up. Of course you should use your own pattern here and chain alternative downstream jQuery methods, I am using it as a proof-of-concept :)

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-image').match(/http:\/\/placehold\.it/gi);
}).slideUp();
```

It works for both background images being specified through CSS, or through inline style attribute.

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/nmw9a4hk/2/

---

OP asked if it is possible to define the regexp outside of the filter function separately. Yes, it is possible:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("http:\/\/placehold\.it", "gi");

$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-image').match(pattern);
}).slideUp();
```

See updated demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/nmw9a4hk/12/

Comment: Thanks - I'm having trouble trying to define and substitute a variable for the match string. Seems like it needs a new RegExp constructor to put a variable together with '/g' -- like `var theRegex = "1600x50";` then `.match(new RegExp(theRegex, "\/g"));` ? however this is not working

Comment: @nimmolo, you'll want to do `new RegExp(theRegex, "g")`. But I recommend placing that logic outside of the `.filter()` function, otherwise you are going to be wasting efficiency recreating the same expression multiple times. So `theRegex = new RegExp(theRegex, "g")`, and then inside the callable function `.match(theRegex)`.

Comment: @nimmolo I have updated the answer to include the scenario where you want to pre-define the pattern. Updated the demo, too: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/nmw9a4hk/12/

Comment: @Sam @Terry thanks. Since i want to strip out the regex if (condition met) I've updated the jsfiddle to remove the pattern from `background-image` on `click`. It's not working, but what I've got is intended to collect the divs with the pattern in a variable `divs` and then replace the string on `each` with an empty string. http://jsfiddle.net/nmw9a4hk/13/

Comment: `this` in *that* context is just an HTML element, you will need to turn it into a jQuery element to use `.css()` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmw9a4hk/14/)). Depending on what your expression replaces, you may just be able to set the `background-image` property to `none` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmw9a4hk/16/)).

Comment: @nimmolo Precisely what @Sam has said. You will need to use `$(this)` as it is a jQuery object which methods will apply, while `this` is simply a HTML node that jQuery methods will not apply. If you change the line to `$(this).css("background-image", "none");` in the `.each()` look, things will work: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/nmw9a4hk/15/

Comment: woohoo! thanks both of you. if i had any rep points, i'd vote it up