# get background image url using attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use attr('style') and able to get below's value,

```
background-image: url(http://example.com/img/123456-bg.jpg); background-size: cover;
```

but how to proceed to get

```
123456-bg
```

Comment: What about .css(element) .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get URL from background-image Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397529/get-url-from-background-image-property)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
var $div = $('#mydiv'),
  bimg = $div.css('background-image');
var match = bimg.match(/\d+-bg/),
  value = match ? match[0] : undefined;

snippet.log(value)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<!-- To show result in the dom instead of console, only to be used in the snippet not in production -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" style="background-image: url(http://example.com/img/123456-bg.jpg); background-size: cover;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

More or less like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/stdob/52ok19gr/3/

```
var url = $("#div").css('background-image');

var m = new URL(url.match(/url\((.*)\)/).pop());

m.filename = (m.pathname).substring( (m.pathname).lastIndexOf('/')+1 );

m.basename = m.filename.match(/(.*)\.(.*)/)[1];

console.log(m);
```

Comment: why not directly `m.filename`? I am using Chrome and in the URL object there is filename attribute, why to substring it from pathname

Comment: If I understand correctly TS, he needs to get the base name?

Comment: URL has no `filename` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

'.css("background-image")'

Comment: still couldn't  find the exact img id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var index = yourUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var img = yourUrl.substr(index);
var imgName = img.substr(0, img.indexOf('.'));
alert(imgName);
```

Comment: if you need to get your URL of background image, share your html code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var imageName = $('#yourDiv').css('background-image').match(/img\/(.*)\.jpg/)[1];
```