# jQuery get background image URL without the quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use jQuery to get the background image URL of a div but without any quotes.

So basically all I need is the URL/Path to the image.

I'm using the code bellow but this code gives me a URL like this:

```
"http://somesite.com/images/apple.png"
```

As you can see, it will place the URL between double quotes which is not what I want.

**Here is the code:**

```
var bg = $('.selected').css('background-image');
bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');

alert(bg);
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing with RegEx `/"/g` will give me what you want:

```js
alert(
  '"http://somesite.com/images/apple.png"'
    .replace(/"/g, "")
);
```

Comment: sure. will do. I always select correct answers any how ;)

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways

```
var bg_img = $('body').css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1');

var bgImage = $('#content').css('background-image').replace(/^url|[\(\)]/g, '');
```

These stack overflow qns can help you

[Get URL from background-image Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397529/get-url-from-background-image-property)

Comment: Omar, if you find a duplicate, and it solves the question, kindly use the duplicate option.

Comment: cheers omar. that helps too.

Comment: Will do that..thanks!