# get the background url from inline css with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the background-image: url('XXX');

this is how I'm getting all the inline css

Can somebody help me to get only the url of the background-image.
Thanks

```js
$('.c-image').click(function() {
  var x = $('.colored').attr('style');
  console.log(x)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c-image">
  <span class="c-background">Outer Span
    <span class="colored" style= "background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url('0963870.jpg'); ">Inner Span</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `.css("background-image");` will give you the value, which you can concatenatet to `"background-image: "`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery get background image URL without the quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676501/jquery-get-background-image-url-without-the-quotes)

Comment: There is no element in the HTML you've shown with the class `colored`...

Comment: @NickParsons its giving me this error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).css is not a function

Comment: I made you a snippet. It is not a [mcve] -  there is nothing with class=colored

Comment: @Albandenica that error means that the `$` variable is not a reference to `jQuery`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ye I accidentally remove it, I'm updating the question now

Comment: @Albandenica Use it on colored instead: `$('.colored').css("background-image")`. Now that I'm re-reading your question, do you want to get the url from wtithin `url()` or the style?

Comment: @B001 its giving me with url

Comment: @NickParsons yes I want only the url inside () not with brackets and others

Comment: @s.kuznetsov its giving me the url like this "875213.jpeg", I want to be just 875213.jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get url address without **quotes** use `css()` method and method `replace()`.

```js
$(".colored").click(function () {
    let cleanUrl = $(this).css("background-image").replace('url("', "").replace('")', "");
    console.log(cleanUrl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c-image">
    <span class="c-background">
        Outer Span
        <span class="colored" style="background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(0963870jpg);">Inner Span</span>
    </span>
</div>
```