# Get CSS background-image url from ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get the url from this ID

```
<div id="image" style="background-image: url(/test.com/test.jpg)">
```

Has been searching google and stack overflow for this but only getting "get id from url" or current window location result only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get div's background-image url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809876/can-i-get-divs-background-image-url)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get URL from background-image Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397529/get-url-from-background-image-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use element style `backgroundImage` property:

```js
var img = document.getElementById('image'),
    url = img.style.backgroundImage;

console.log(url);
```

```html
<div id="image" style="background-image: url(/test.com/test.jpg)">
```

Comment: Good to help. If you only want to get "/test.com/test.jpg" you can do: `'url("/test.com/test.jpg")'.split('"')[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#image').css('background-image')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
   $("#image").css("background-image");
```

Answer (score 0):

I sit this to get the value from element with inline style properties.

```
var imgUrl = $("#image").prop("style", "background-image");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var x=$("#image").css("background-image");
 var imageurl = x.substring(5,x.length-2);
 alert(imageurl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="image" style="background-image: url(//test.com/test.jpg); height: 230px" class="testclass">Image</div>
```