# Get background image url value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mongodb

I am trying to get the value of the backgound-image url. The url is set inline directly in the element tag with the style attribute like so

`<a style="background-image: url(https:// ....)"></a>`

I tried doing

`var url = $(this).css('background-image')`

with various regexes but it does not seem to work. I am trying to store this URL into MongoDB but I get this error

`var styles = parse(el.attribs.style);`
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'attribs' of undefined`

Comment: Can you paste in a larger snippet of your javascript? It's unclear what `this` is in your jQuery snippet, and the error you are showing seems to indicate that you are not successfully selecting the element.

Comment: `el.attribs.style` should be `el.attributes.style` or `el.getAttribute("style")`, but using `$(el).css('background-image')` would be the best way. What's not working about it?

Comment: I think what he needs is a regex so he can extract 'https://theurl.com' instead of saving the whole value 'url("https://theurl.com")'.

Comment: I tried doing this from another thread about this topic `url = url.replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');` but it does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get URL from background-image Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397529/get-url-from-background-image-property)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the style value, then strip the URL from it

```
var bi = $('a').css("background-image");
alert(bi.split(/"/)[1]);
```

The call to jQuery .css("background-image") always returns the URL within double quotes, regardless how it was set originally.

Sample fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6qk3ufcb/

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla JS, having full DOM access, it can be done like so:

```
document.querySelector('a').style.backgroundImage.split('"')[1]
```

Or, if for whatever reason you don't have DOM access (for example dealing in node, and operating on some simplified HTML parser) it can also be done with regexp:

```
const htmlString = `<div class="bg-div" style="background-image: url('https://loremipsum.com/imageIpsum.jpg');">`

const reg = /url.'([\w\W]+?)'/;
const searched = reg.exec(htmlString)
console.log(searched[1]) //=> https://loremipsum.com/imageIpsum.jpg
```